# Dynamic link redirect through .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello
I have a link like              http://blog.acode.com/2010/06/git-in-windows/
now I want to redirect it to    http://acode.com/2010/06/git-in-windows/

But "2010/06/git-in-windows/" this part is not a static string this might change depending on blog content dynamically.

How to do this this .htaccess or php scripts or with both ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will move redirect any link from `blog.acode.com` to `acode.com` while keeping the path of the url intact. It basically just removes `blog` from the link and sends it back.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.acode.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://acode.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You should complement this action by updating your blogging software with the new domain name. Failing to do so might lead to unnecessary complications, that could not even be noticed.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do this in a dynamic fashion is through mod_rewrite. A rule like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.acode.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://acode.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

This will match all incoming requests to blog.acode.com, match the whole path and then redirect it to acode.com.