# htaccess rule for url redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

http://abc.com/forum/forum/topic/topic-1/

to

http://abc.com/forum/topic/topic-1/

please help me to write htaccess rule to get above url .

I want to remove extra 'forum' from the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code inside htaccess file:

redirect http://abc.com/forum/forum/topic/topic-1/ http://abc.com/forum/topic/topic-1/

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. /topic/topic-1/ will be dynamic, any solution for it ?

Comment: ok then see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613901/dynamic-link-redirect-through-htaccess.  May be it helps you.